# Generate a new message, record or documents in elastic index

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

currently I am using JDBC plugin to run some statements from the database, so I would like to track the results returned from this database, sometimes this statements doesn't returned any data to stored in the elastic index, so I need to generate a new message or a new document in the index when there is no data

```
filter {
  if "xxx" in [tags] {
    split { field => "status1" }
    clone { clones => ["status11"] }
    mutate { add_field => {"colume1" => "value1"} } }
  else {
   split { field => "status2" }
   clone { clones => ["status22"] }
   mutate { add_field => {"colume2" => "value2"} } }
}
```